# Python Import and 'object has no attribute' with Qt

Tags: python, qt, import, pyqt

From research on Stack Overflow and other sites I'm 99% sure that the problem I'm having is due to incorrect importing.  Below is a QLabel sub class that I'm using to respond to some mouse events:

```
import Qt
import sys

class ASMovableLabel(Qt.QLabel):

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):

        button = event.button()
        if button == 1:
            print ('LEFT CLICK')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        button = event.button()
        if button == 1:
            print ('LEFT CLICK')
        elif button == 3:
            print ('RIGHT CLICK')
            self.setLayout()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print ("you moved the mouse: %f, %f", event.x, event.y)
        self.frameRect.setTopLeft(Qt.QPoint(event.x, event.y))
```

When mouseMoveEvent is triggered I get the following error:

```
    self.frameRect.setTopLeft(Qt.QPoint(event.x, event.y))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'setTopLeft'
```

The other solutions to this type of error I've seen have revolved around the name space, so I would or would not need to include `Qt.` before all the Qt classes but this error is much farther down in the Qt objects.  Please point out my mistake!

I have also tried:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt
```

It gives the same error

UPDATE: based on Messa's comment I made few changes:

```
import Qt
import sys

class ASMovableLabel(Qt.QLabel):

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):

        button = event.button()
        if button == 1:
            print ('LEFT CLICK')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        button = event.button()
        if button == 1:
            print ('LEFT CLICK')
        elif button == 3:
            print ('RIGHT CLICK')
            self.setLayout() #this won't set to nil

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.frameRect().setTopLeft(Qt.QPoint(event.globalX(), event.globalY()))
```

So it seems that in Python the dot syntax are function calls and need to include that trailing "`()`".  This doesn't include `self` ( i.e. s`elf().something()` )

Comment: Ad "in Python the dot syntax are function calls" - no, it is just PyQt that follows C++ habits instead of Python habits. Of course if I create my own class that has some frameRect attribute I can write just `self.frameRect.setTopLeft(...)`. In Python I can even write getters/setters for attributes (via `property` decorator), I don't know why they are not used in PyQt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
self.frameRect().setTopLeft(Qt.QPoint(event.x, event.y))
```

instead of

```
self.frameRect.setTopLeft(Qt.QPoint(event.x, event.y))
```